# Understanding the difference between linear and interactive terms in Tukey HSD

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, tukey-hsd-test

I have an analysis of a dataset with a factorial design. Currently, I've been doing the analysis in R, using `aov` and `TukeyHSD`. I am trying to understand the difference between the additive hypothesis test and the interactive effect. Suppose that I have a $2^2$ design. Then, I think an example is the easiest way to put forth where my understanding is failing:

```
# Generate some simulated data
data <- data.frame(
    measurements = rnorm(16, c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(0, 4), rep(3, 4))),
    f1 = factor(c(rep(1, 4), rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(0, 4))),
    f2 = factor(c(rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(0, 4)))
)
# Fit the ANOVA model
model <- aov(measurements~f1*f2, data)
# Perform significance testing with TukeyHSD
sig_test <- TukeyHSD(model)
sig_test
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = measurements ~ f1 * f2, data = data)

$f1
         diff       lwr       upr     p adj
1-0 -2.142063 -3.061534 -1.222592 0.0002725

$f2
         diff       lwr        upr     p adj
1-0 -1.551698 -2.471169 -0.6322276 0.0031664

$`f1:f2`
              diff       lwr        upr     p adj
1:0-0:0 -1.5207097 -3.292567  0.2511478 0.1020317
0:1-0:0 -0.9303453 -2.702203  0.8415122 0.4357773
1:1-0:0 -3.6937615 -5.465619 -1.9219039 0.0002360
0:1-1:0  0.5903645 -1.181493  2.3622220 0.7581981
1:1-1:0 -2.1730517 -3.944909 -0.4011942 0.0154564
1:1-0:1 -2.7634162 -4.535274 -0.9915586 0.0028087
```

Now, I am trying to understand, what is the difference between `1:0-0:0` and `$f1` as well as `0:1-0:0` and `$f2`? To me, they should be the same thing, but I realize the way you distribute the error in the model will be different between the additive and interactive parts. What is the intuitive difference between them??

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful if you leave the levels of *f1* as *0* and *1* and change the levels of *f2* to *a* and *b*.

As you have the data set up, to answer the question in simplified notation, *$f1* is like *1:(1&0) - 0(1&0)*, and *f2* is like *(1&0):1 - (1&0):0*.